Two example of non-$\omega$ models in Kunen.
In Kunens "Set Theory An Introduction to Independence Proofs" page 146, chapter IV, we are given the following:

$\ldots$ For example, let $S$ be $\sf{ZF}+ \neg \sf{CON}(\ulcorner \sf{ZF} \urcorner)$. $S$ is consistent by Gödel Incompleteness Theorem. If $\mathfrak{U} \models S$ then $\mathfrak{U}$ contains a proof of contradiction from $\sf{ZF}$. However, since $\sf{ZF}$ is really consistent this must be a non-standard proof, so $\mathfrak{U}$ is not an $\omega$-model.

Is the idea here: Assume that $S$ was inconsistent, but that $\sf{ZF}$ was consistent. Then $\sf{ZF}+\neg \sf{CON}(\ulcorner \sf{ZF} \urcorner)$ would be inconsistent. Consider Gödels $2^{\text{nd}}$ incompleteness theorem, which says that (in atleast one formulation), if we assume that $\sf{ZF}$ is consistent, then $\sf{ZF} \not \vdash \sf{CON}(\ulcorner \sf{ZF} \urcorner)$. So, unless I am mistaken, generally, if $A$ is consistent and we know that $A + B$ is inconsistent, then it follows that $A \vdash \neg B$, since if $A \vdash B$ then $A \vdash B \vdash \bot$ so by transitivity of $\vdash$, $A$ would be inconsistent. Applying this here, we see that then $\sf{ZF} \vdash \neg(\neg \sf{CON}(\ulcorner \sf{ZF} \urcorner) = \sf{CON}(\ulcorner \sf{ZF} \urcorner)$ would hold, contradicting Gödels $2^{\text{nd}}$ incompleteness. So if $\mathfrak{U}$ models $S$, then I suppose it should model $\neg \sf{CON}(\ulcorner \sf{ZF} \urcorner)$, i.e. we can prove a contradiction from $\sf{ZF}$; but since $S$ is consistent, in particular, $\sf{ZF}$ is consistent. Why does it follow that then that this must be a non-standard proof; is it because if $\mathfrak{U} \models \sf{ZF}$, then for each formula $\phi$ in the metatheory, there is a corresponding $\phi^{\mathfrak{U}} \in A$ (assuming $\mathfrak{U} = \langle A,E \rangle$), where $\phi^{\mathfrak{U}}$ is the interpretation of $\ulcorner \phi \urcorner$ in $\mathfrak{U}$, if $\mathfrak{U}$ is a $\omega$-model, then these are the only formulas of $\mathfrak{U}$?
The other example given is the following:

In the metatheory, let $\phi_n(n \in \omega)$ be a recursive listing of $S$. We may now formalize this listing within $S$. In $S$, we may define $c$ to be the largest $x \in \omega$ such that $$\exists \beta(R(\beta) \models \{\phi_n : n < x\}).$$ This is a meaningful definition within $S$ since $S \vdash \neg(\sf{CON}(\ulcorner S \urcorner)$ (my comment: why does this imply that this is a meaningful definition?). By the reflection theorem, $S \vdash (c > \ulcorner n \urcorner)$ for all standard $n$, so whenever $\mathfrak{U} \models S$, $c^{\mathfrak{U}}$ is a non-standard natural number. Now, in $S$, define $b$ to be the least ordinal $\beta$ such that $R(\beta) \models \{\phi_n: n < c\}$. Then $R(b)^{\mathfrak{U}}$ is a model for each standard axiom $\phi_n$ of $S$, but fails to satisfy some non-standard axioms. $\ldots$ $S$ defines a transitive set, $R(b)$, such that for each axiom $\phi$ of $S$, $S \vdash (R(b) \models \phi)$, even though $S$ cannot prove, and in fact, refutes $\exists \mathfrak{M}(\mathfrak{M} \models \ulcorner S \urcorner)$.

Things I find confusing: By definition of $c$, together with reflection ($\sf{ZF} \vdash \forall \beta \ \exists \alpha > \alpha(\phi_1,\ldots,\phi_n \ \text{are absolute for} \ R(\alpha))$) gives us that for all formulas $\phi_1,\ldots, \phi_n$, and some $\beta$ so that $R(\beta) \models \phi_1,\ldots,\phi_n$, there is an $\alpha$ so that $\alpha > \beta$ and $\phi_1,\ldots,\phi_n$ are absolute for $R(\alpha)$. But how do we then use reflection (I have not covered $\S7$ in IV, Kunen, yet) to see that $R(\alpha) \models \phi_1,\ldots,\phi_n$? There are more things I find confusing, but I don't want to overwhelm the reader.
I am generally quite confused about what takes place in the metatheory and what takes place in some formalization of set theory, in this proof. Is $S$ in the metatheory, or is $S$ formalized set theory? For example, it seems that $S \vdash (R(b) \models \phi)$ for all $\phi$ in $S$, but clearly it fails for any model $\mathfrak{U}$ of $S$. For example, is $S \vdash (R(b) \models \phi)$ a statement in the metatheory or in formalized set theory?
I know my questions are somewhat confused; I think generally I am most confused as to what is formalized and what is metatheoretical in the proof. I'd be happy for clarification.

For the second part, the idea is that $\phi_1,\ldots,\phi_n $ are theorems of $S.$ So them being absolute for $R(\alpha)$ means the same thing as them being true in $R(\alpha).$

You may benefit from reading JDH's less formalistic telling of the same story here

To the first part, the intuition that needs to be built here (and I think can be only built by carefully walking through) is that when you have some nice computational process defined by recursion, what it looks like inside a non-$\omega$-model, running on standard inputs and a standard number of steps, is exactly the same as it looks in real life. Proof verification is a finite computational process (bounded by the length of a proof). So if we take a number and run our proof verification program on it inside a model, it will verify if and only if it actually is the code of a proof.
